# Dynamically adding HTML5 Date Element iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, mobile-safari

I have the following javascript code that uses jQuery to append a HTML5 date input element to an existing div element and sets the value to a certain date (format of the date is yyyy-MM-dd).  This code works perfectly in Chrome, Safari (desktop), IE (tested with IE 11).  But when the code runs on a mobile-safari the input element is appended but the default date value isn't set.

Code:

```
$("<input>").attr({
    type: "date",
    value: "2014-07-31",
    id: "someDate"
}).appendTo("#someDiv");
```

Does anyone know why the default date is not being set on Mobile Safari?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of IOS ?

Comment: The version of iOS is 7.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should insert the element into the dom before setting the value. Not sure if this works, try it and let me know.

```
$('<input type="date" id="#someDate">').appendTo("#someDiv").val("2014-07-31");
```

or you could try `$('#someDate').val("2014-07-31");` if appendTo doesn't chain.

Also, the input type is readonly, so setting the attribute on the  element may not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks B2K..I have tried alerting the value of the element after it has been appended. The value is what I would expect it to be, it just doesn't visibly appear to have an value.

Comment: Can you just do a document.write so that the element gets inserted before the dom is loaded?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem.  Might not be the cleanest but it works.  

'code'
 $("<input>").attr({
    type: "text",
    value: "2014-07-31",
    id: "someDate"
}).appendTo("#someDiv");

document.getElementById("someDate").type = "date";
'code'

I don't really have a good technical answer, but my guess is that setting an input type to date using jquery doesn't behave like you would expect it to.  I was reading up on changing an input type using jquery is not allowed maybe that is somewhat related to this issue.  Thanks for your help though!